# Why is csv.reader not correctly outputting data?

Tags: python, csv, csvreader

My python code features a section which processes .pcap files into .csv files. Upon opening these files in excel, they are correctly formatted into cells, or if opened in a text editor, they are correctly formatted with "," delimiters.

However, when using `csv.reader`, the file's data is not correctly outputted. The code is here:

```py
for file in os.listdir(__directory):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        csv_reader = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(row)
```

The text file contents contain source and destination IPs, as well as TTL values. `print(row)` oddly outputs the source and destination IPs, however not the TTL values. Also, the IPs are separated with a "'" instead of with a ",". And in some cases, the delimiter is outputted instead.

For example, when the text file may contain:

```
0.0.0.0,1.1.1.1,128
```

It may be outputted as

```
0.0.0.0'1.1.1.1
```

EDIT:

```
for file in os.listdir(__directory):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        with open(os.path.join(__directory, file)) as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            for row in csv_reader:
                print(row)
```

This edit from the previous code outputs the desired results (as Ture mentioned in the comments). I am not sure why...

Comment: That's odd. I can't seem to get any issue when reading a file with `0.0.0.0,1.1.1.1,128` as the only line in it using the same code you posted.

Comment: The csv reader returns lists, so you'd expect `print(row)` to print something like `['0.0.0.0', '1.1.1.1', 128]`, which it does, when I try it. This needs a reproducible example.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Make certain that you can verify the *exact* contents of the file, *possibly including unprintable characters*. Make certain that you know the *encoding* of the file, and that you specify the right encoding when opening the file. Using the data that you show does not allow any of us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The file is actually 101 lines in length, however I just gave an example of what one line looked like. I apologize for the confusion, I should have clarified myself on this and included a reproducable example. Regardless, I did edit my question, as I have resolved the issue - alhough quite frankly, I am not sure why the fix works. Any explaination on it would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that the first version simply opens the wrong file (because of the missing os.path.join)? This is why examples should be *complete* and *minimal*. There are too many unknowns, both in the first example and the "fixed" one, for an outsider to be able to tell what the difference is.